# Display Custom Data in Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, geojson

I am trying to replace the default location points and addresses with my own points and addresses.  I have uploaded a geojson with parcel centroid points, address, and assessor parcel number.  I would like to display this information when the user clicks on an address.  Is this possible?

[geojson upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ME3Bo.png)

Answer (score -1):

You can follow this [add points to a web map](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/add-points-pt-1/) tutorial series to achieve the functionality you are looking for. Since it sounds like you have already uploaded your data to Mapbox as a dataset or tileset, the next steps will be to [create a style](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/add-points-pt-2/) and then [add interactivity](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/add-points-pt-3/) by displaying popups containing the desired information when clicked.